# Building Model Using Factory Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, ioc-container, eloquent, service-provider

I am trying to build/factor model using Service Provider but I seem to be missing a step or two to make it work.

Below is my service provider

```
class TranslationProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        $this->app->bind(TranslatableModel::class, function($app){
            $translation =  \App::make(Repository::class);
            $model =  (new TranslatableModel())->setTranslationRepository($translation);
            return $model;
        });

    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

and here is my TranslatableModel

```
class TranslatableModel extends Model
{
    use Translatable, TranslationTrait;

    /** @var \App\Repositories\Translation\Repository $translationRepository */
    public $translationRepository;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    public function setTranslationRepository(Repository $repo)
    {
        $this->translationRepository = $repo;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I know I am trying to inject a Repository into model, and I know the case should be the opposite, However my logic relies on this kind of scenario. I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of using \App::make(Repository::class) inside the model would result in serialization 500 error on closures.

The workaround was to create service Provider and Facade for it as shown below.

```
<?php
namespace App\Facades;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Translate extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'Translate';
    }

}
```

Instantiate my class using service provider singleton as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Repositories\Translation\Repository;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TranslationProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Translate', function() {
            return \App::make(Repository::class);
        });
    }
}
```

Now inside my TransalatableModel I would refer to the Translate Repository using Facade as follow:

```
@Translate::translateText($this->short_description, 'en', 'ar')[0];
```